# programing diff vim function, vim diff mapping

Tags: vim

I've found [this function](http://www.bestofvim.com/tip/diff-diff/):

```
" Set up a keymapping from <Leader>df to a function call.
" (Note the function doesn't need to be defined beforehand.)
" Run this mapping silently. That is, when I call this mapping,
" don't bother showing "call DiffToggle()" on the command line.
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>df :call DiffToggle()<CR>

" Define a function called DiffToggle.
" The ! overwrites any existing definition by this name.
function! DiffToggle()
    " Test the setting 'diff', to see if it's on or off.
    " (Any :set option can be tested with &name.
    " See :help expr-option.)
    if &diff
        diffoff
    else
        diffthis
    endif
:endfunction
```

Now I would like to add an extra condition, if there is some selected text (visual mode) call another command instead of `diffthis`, [`Linediff`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3745)

Reading the function I guess I need some extra set option to test, like they did with `&dif` but with the visual option. Something like:

```
function! DiffToggle()
    if &dif
        diffoff
    elseif &visual
        Linediff
    else
        diffthis
    endif
:endfunction
```

This doesn't work, but does anyone have any clue to make it work?
Also, it would be very useful any reference about what and how many setting variables of this kind are in vim.

**Edit**
I ended up with this in my vimrc, (works):

```
"LINEDIFF/VIMDIFF
 "--------------

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>df :call DiffToggle('n')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <Leader>df :call DiffToggle('x')<CR>

function! DiffToggle(mode) range
    echo "difftoggle..."
    if &diff
        diffoff
        echo "diffoff..."
    else
        if a:mode=='x'
            echo "linediff..."
            echo a:firstline."---".a:lastline
            call linediff#Linediff(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        else
            echo "diff..."
            diffthis
        endif
    endif
:endfunction
```

Comment: `elseif has('visual')` ?
`:help has()`

Comment: Or if you need check current mode (visual, insert, normal etc) call `mode()`.

Comment: has() only tells you if the feature is supported, so in my case always returns 1

Comment: but vim has no option called `visual`.
Check this out `:he option-summary`

Comment: I see, I've just checked it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call a slightly different function from  `xnoremap <Leader>df ...` ? That one will be called when you are in visual mode.

Or, pass the mode as argument to your function:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>df :call DiffToggle('n')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <Leader>df :call DiffToggle('x')<CR>
```

... and check `a:mode` inside your function, having the following prototype:

```
function! DiffToggle(mode)
```

Comment: Hi Laser, I tried but it doesn't work properly, now it executes DiffToggle once per line selected in visualmode. Can I make it to execute it just once?

Comment: I think you'll need to add the `range` keyword to your function prototype (`h: function`, `/range`) "   When the [range] argument is added, the function is expected to take care of a range itself.  The range is passed as "a:firstline" and "a:lastline".  If [range] is excluded, ":{range}call" will call the function for each line in the range, with the cursor on the start of each line.  See |function-range-example|."

Comment: Nice, now it runs only once but the range sets only to the current line (not the several lines selected). BTW now I'm busy but I''ll give it more tries later. Thanks a lot for your suggestions

Comment: The range is used only in visual mode, and you have to handle that case yourself, i.e. read all the lines (e.g. with `getline(i)` with `i` moving from `a:firstline` to `a:lastline`).